# setcookie usage for multiple localhost subdomains

Tags: php, cookies, localhost, session-cookies, setcookie

I have been working on a web application on my localhost (xampp) where I have two subdomains set up. Lets call these domains abc.localhost and xyz.localhost.

I have both of these set up in my host file to have an entry of

```
127.0.0.1 abc.localhost
127.0.0.1 xyz.localhost
```

I also have them set up in my vhost file like normal pointing to different locations.

My application is set up to go through abc.localhost first which is where i set up some cookies

```
setcookie('AUTHORIZATION', time()+3600, 0, '/', '.localhost');
setcookie('SOMEOTHERCOOKIE','here is the val',0,'/','.localhost');
```

this then forwards the user to xyz.localhost.  In order for the user to get access to xyz.localhost the authorization has to be set by abc.localhost and pass over a cookie.

I have tried to change the ".localhost" to be xyz.localhost and every other combination i can think of.  Leaving off the . does not work either.

Please help me figure this out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set cookies for a top level domain (the last part of a domain). To achieve what you want change your HOST entries to abc.myproject.loc and xyz.myproject.loc or something alike.

Then you can set your cookies for myproject.loc.

Comment: Shouldnt I be able to set the cookie for xyz.localhost though?

Comment: Yes you can, but then it will be accessible for abc.xyz.localhost etc. but not for abc.localhost. But localhost is a very special domain, so there might some more special handling for it implemented in your browser.